# Batch file - Write list of files to variable

Tags: directory, batch-file

I'd like to get a list of all files (including their absolute path) into a variable, separated by spaces.  My Google-fu seems to be weak in this regard, because I keep running into issues.

I have a base directory stored in `%baseDir%`, and would like to parse it for files (not recursing or including sub-directories).  Like I mentioned, this needs to go into a list.  I'd imagine there's a nice little shortcut I could use, but a for loop and concatenation would do the trick as well.

Ideally, I'd have something like this:

```
echo fileList

C:\file1.c C:\file2.c C:\file3.c
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in (%baseDir%\*) do set LIST=!LIST! %%x
set LIST=%LIST:~1%
```

In fact, you find this very example also in the help for the `set` command, accessible via `help set`, complete with an explanation why the naïve approach won't work.

To use a different set of files (rather than *all*), you can easily change the wildcard:

```
for %%x in (%baseDir%\*.c) do set LIST=!LIST! %%x
```

Comment: @espais: It's a pretty common one; I think I answered it roughly a dozen times by now ;-)

Comment: @Johannes...quick followup...is it easy to restrict this snippet to files of only *.c type?

Comment: @espais: Of course: Just use `%baseDir%\*.c` as the wildcard.

Comment: Ok, comment formatting stupidity strikes again; yay. I edited it into the answer, now without the backslash gone missing.

Comment: Is it possible to do this recursively?

Comment: @Viktor: Take a look at `help for` which will tell you to use the `/r` switch to `for` for that purpose.