# Creating a list of files within a BAT file

Tags: list, variables, batch-file, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch file - Write list of files to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238433/batch-file-write-list-of-files-to-variable)

Within a batch file, I'm trying to create a list of all the PDF files in a directory and its subfolders, and store this information in a variable using *set*.

For example, if *parentDirectory* contained *1.pdf, 2.pdf,* and *3.pdf* in itself and its subfolders:

cd *parentDirectory*
set pdfList =
*-code for populating the list goes here-*
*Now pdfList contains* "1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal
cd ..

if exist *.pdf(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do call :append %%a
)
echo pdfList: %pdfList%
goto :eof

:append
if defined pdfList (
    set pdfList=%pdfList% %1
) else (
    set pdfList=%1
)
```

This will add the list of PDF filenames separated by spaces to the `pdfList` variable. If you want to include the PDF filenames in all subdirectories as well, then change the `dir` command in the `for` statement to:

```
dir /s /b *.pdf
```

But using this will have a side-effect that a list of absolute paths would be added to the `pdfList` variable, and not relative paths as you expressed in your question.

The first `if` statement ensures that we execute the `dir` command only if PDF files are present. We don't want to invoke DIR command if they are not present; otherwise `dir` would print 'File not found' error.

The `:append` subroutine is necessary because if we try to append to the `pdfList` variable in the `for` statement itself, we'll find that the updated value of `pdfList` in one iteration doesn't survive till the next iteration.

The `if` statement in the `:append` subroutine is to make sure that we do not have a leading space in the value of `pdfList`.