# Windows Batch - get folder name inside a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a question on creating a batch script. I want to get the folder name as a variable in inside a path. For example:

I have a path, `E:\` and there is several folders, i.e., `E:\folderA`, `E:\folderB`.

Could anyone tell me how to run a for loop and set the name of the two folders, `folderA` and `folderB`, inside a variable in a for loop using batch file?

Comment: If you already know the names of the folders why don't you just hard code them as variables?

Comment: @Squashman likely OP mixed up i.e. and eg.

Allen, is it always two folders, or the first two, or zero or more? do you want a list of them in one variable, or one variable per folder? Do you have powershell available, or would it need to be in "plain cmd"?

Comment: this might get you going: [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540089/how-to-get-the-list-of-filenames-in-a-directory-and-store-that-in-a-variable-usi)

Comment: i am going to use plain cmd now. Since there will be multiple folders (ie, more than 2) and I have no control of the folder name (ie, I would not know the name). I want to set the folder name in a variable so that I can edit the folder one by one (like renaming, etc.).

Comment: I guess you are looking for `for /D %I in ("E:\") do echo %~nxI` -- right?